# Why Async requests are destroyed when main thread end? Spring Tasks

Tags: multithreading, spring, asynchronous, spring-integration, spring-io

I wanted to write async method.

```
@Component
public class TaskImpl implements Task{

    @Async(value="myExecutor")
    public void async(int n) throws InterruptedException{
        log.info("Executing task"+n);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        log.info("Finished executing task" +n);

    }

}
```

It is nice! I have config like that:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />    
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="3" />
```

That's nice! I have write test class too!

```
    @Autowired
    private Task task;

    @Test
    public void mailSendTest() throws InterruptedException{
        for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
            task.async(i);
        }
        Thread.sleep(3000)

    }
```

I have tested and **async works very well!** tasks are in parallel!

**Question 1.**
but when main thread of test case destroys ,Execute threads does not work. In the other words, If I do not write Thread.sleep() in test cases, Executor is shooting down immediately. How can I fix that?

```
2015-03-12 17:02:26.706  INFO ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: Shutting down ExecutorService
```

I do not want to write JOIN or Sleep.

**Question 2.**
I need async() method in order to invoke mail sender class. In the other words I have written this component.

```
@Component
public class MailMail {

    private MailSender mailSender;

    public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @Async
    public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String msg)   {

        ....
    }


    }
}
```

Now I'm interested how to solve the following problem. Might be there is communication , network problem, and I can't send email. what happens now? how to catch exception and send it again?

Answer (score 0):

For the test-case you can `Mockito.spy` your `TaskImpl` and use `CountDownLetch` from the `doAnswer()` and wait for the letch in the end of test method.

For error handling from those async task you can use `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` from Spring Integration and supply it with the `ErrorHandler`

Comment: thank you! But I have another question. In test case I can write thread.join() too, it is not problem. But in real application I should listen, when tasks will be done , after that I should destroy main thread. In the other words while(tasks are executing){  // waiting, thread is alive}

Comment: `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` has `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` and `awaitTerminationSeconds` options

Comment: thank you. But I just call interface method.  I do not use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor . I have that configuration in XML. Can I retrieve ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  initialized object?

Comment: Instead of using that `<task:executor>` use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` directly from `<bean>`

Comment: waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown does not shut down java class at all. I want to shut down when everything will be finished.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You just do `applicationContext.close()` on shutdown and it will wait for those tasks.